# Selecting records in order of parent id

Tags: mysql

Simple question.. just can't get the result set in the order I need :p

I have a table "categories"

```
id    | name     | parent
1       apple      0
2       macintosh  1
3       atari      0
4       st         3
5       lisa       1
```

I'm trying to select get the following result set:

```
1   apple      0
5   lisa       1
2   macintosh  1
3   atari      0
4   st         3
```

So in other words  I want all columns of all rows, where rows with parents are immediately after their parent row and all are sorted alphabetically.

```
parent a
 child a
 child b
parent b
 child a
```

The query I'm using now doesn't correctly re-order the rows after their parents

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM categories a RIGHT JOIN categories b ON b.parent = a.id
```

Comment: @Fo - Seems to be a typo ? Atari should listed right after apple

Comment: No, the children of apple should be listed after apple, then atari, then the children of atari. (Lisa was the computer Apple released before the Macintosh)

Comment: What about the grandchilden? I take it that they should be sorted as well (i.e.: recursively)?

Comment: I don't anticipate having grandchildren in this particular table, but it wouldn't hurt

Comment: my answer has a for 2 and 3 levels, in the mysql syntax your label indicates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a simple, perhaps suboptimally-scalable solution, I recommend hard-coding this with the maximum number of levels you will have:

For 2 levels only:

```
SELECT p2.name as `Parent name`, p1.*
FROM categories p1
LEFT JOIN categories p2 on p1.categories_id = p2.id
```

You're really asking about sorting, so I'd recommend generating a "path"-like string:
(see below for sample output of this query)

```
SELECT Concat(If(isnull(p2.name),"",Concat("/",p2.name)),"/",p1.name) as `generated path`, p2.name as `Parent name`, p1.*
FROM categories p1
LEFT JOIN categories p2 on p1.parent_id = p2.id
order by `generated path`
```

For 3 levels, though your data doesn't have this yet -- path omitted because it will get ugly :)

```
SELECT p3.name as `Grandparent name`, p2.name as `Parent name`, p1.*
FROM categories p1
LEFT JOIN categories p2 on p1.categories_id = p2.id
LEFT JOIN categories p3 on p2.categories_id = p3.id
```

A more comprehensive solution for quickly selecting all items in a particular category at any level, which does require some work on all writes, is implementing a ['right' and 'left' numbering concept](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/2). But, further discussion on that is almost certainly going beyond the scope of what you're asking. However, that's the only good way in my experience to make this kind of self-referencing table very useful if it's going to get big (maybe after 1000+ rows with 3 to 10 levels).

Addendum: sample output from the second query:

```
generated path         Parent name         id         name         parent_id
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/apple                                      1         apple                0
/apple/lisa                  apple          5         lisa                 1
/apple/mac                   apple          2         mac                  1
/atari                                      3         atari                0
/atari/st                    atari          4         st                   3
```

Comment: p.s. I've successfully implemented a self-referential table with a depth of 4, so there's nothing wrong with that approach. Just needs to stay somewhat light, maybe operate on mostly static data, and cache the result.

Comment: This works best to solve the problem as described without requiring a change to data.

Answer (score 14):

If those with no parents had `null` in their `parent` column, your statement would be very simple:

```
SELECT id, name, parent FROM categories order by coalesce(parent, id), id;
```

If you insist on `0` representing no parent, you can use more verbose `CASE WHEN ... THEN ...` statement.

Edit:

```
-- Sorting by name instead
select a.id, a.name, a.parent 
from categories a left join categories b on a.parent=b.id 
order by coalesce(b.name, a.name), a.name
```

Comment: Does this work in MySQL? (I avoid nulls, but that almost sounds useful.)

Comment: @zanlok: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: @cababunga: +1. You get the NULLs from the RIGHT JOIN (see variant in my answer), and you could also create them with NULLIF().

Comment: Definitely not insisting on 0, switched them to null and, the query works great except for ordering alphabetically first by parents then by children.

Comment: hate to sound obnoxious, but my answer handles that and didn't require switching anything to null

Comment: Sorting children by name is easy; you just change last sorting term from `id` to `name`.

Comment: @cababunga, switching the sorting term id to name sorts all the rows by name rather than only the parents, then the children.

Comment: Zanlok, your solution does solve the problem without requiring a change in the data. All parents and children are sorted correctly.

Comment: I meant this order by `coalesce(parent, id), name`. Parents will still be sorted by id. Sorry, I missed that alphabetical sorting in your requirements

Comment: Closer. I can't describe what it's doing now without having a much larger data set.

Comment: Just realized that this last version is what Tomalak suggested long time ago.

Answer (score 3):

This would work, but not recursively.

```
SELECT 
  b.* 
FROM
  categories a 
  RIGHT JOIN categories b ON b.parent = a.id
ORDER BY
  COALESCE(a.name, b.name), b.name
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.name, Table1.parent, Table1_1.name, Table1_1.parent
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table1 AS Table1_1 ON Table1.ID = Table1_1.parent
ORDER BY Table1.name;
```

I built this with Micorsoft Access and it looked like what you wanted to me.  I think you need a report to group on to visually give you what you want to give to a consumer, but for the sake joining correctly to get to that point this works.